# Merge tags [android-camera2] [camera2] [android.harware.camera2]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The three tags are complete synonyms. I believe that the name [android-camera2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-camera2) best expresses the purpose of this tag, even though [camera2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camera2) is shorter. The usage statistics also shows that [android-camera2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-camera2) is most popular.

Comment: [`android.harware.camera2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android.harware.camera2)? `harware`? Really?

Comment: Let me abstain from a religious discussion how easy it is to create a new garbage tag and how hard it is to get it removed.

Comment: @Pang `android.software.camera2` is fancy for 'screenshot'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and merged [android.harware.camera2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android.harware.camera2) into [android-camera2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-camera2) to get rid of that abomination.

I was concerned about any possible confusion with any possible non-Android use of the term "camera2", but none of the questions in [camera2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camera2) seem to be about anything other than Android's Camera2 API. As a result, I've marked [camera2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camera2) as a synonym of [android-camera2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-camera2).

There were 400 questions in the latter, and 175 in the former, so that seems to be the most popular usage in addition to being the most descriptive. If someone has a problem with that, let us know and we can redirect this.